# Given that x has the continued fraction expansion x = [1,$\bar{s}$], show that $ x = 1+ \frac{2}{s+\sqrt{4+s^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, continued-fractions

Let x be a real number and have the continued fraction expansion $x = [1,\bar{s}]$, where s is a natural number and $\bar{s}$ denotes the infinite string $s, s, \ldots $

Let $y = [s, \bar{s}]$ and show $y$ satisfies

$\displaystyle y = s + \frac{1}{y}$

Hence, show that,

$\displaystyle x = 1+ \frac{2}{s+\sqrt{4+s^2}}$

For the first part, I wrote $y =s + \cfrac{1}{s + \cfrac{1}{s + \cfrac{1}{s + \ddots}}} $, then took $\frac{1}{y-s} = \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{s + \cfrac{1}{s + \ddots}}}$, which returned the expansion for y,

meaning y = $\frac{1}{y-s}$
, y = s + $\frac{1}{y}$.

The second part implies that it uses the first, so I tried writing
$\displaystyle x = 1 + \cfrac{1}{s + \cfrac{1}{s + \ddots}}$

and substituting for $y$ to get $x = 1 + (y-s)$, but I could not get further.

Comment: I think the hint meant for you to go a bit further in part 1.

Comment: To offer a more specific hint: can you take $y=s+\frac1y$ and solve for $y$ in terms of $s$? You should be able to reduce the formula to a quadratic equation.

Comment: I have tried to substitute $s = \frac{y^2-1}{y}$ into the expansion for x, but it only leads me back to the original expansion for x once simplified, or functions with higher powers of y or s, which do not seem to simplify.